# error when using filter function to remove rows with missing values in one column

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, na

I get the following message of error when using filter() function to remove rows with missing values in the column "medecin" :

```
"Error in `filter()`:
! Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred."
```

Here is my code :

```
PG_21 <- pg_21 %>%
  filter(medecin != "")
```

And here is the head of my dataset :

```
structure(list(c("9", "9", "9", "1", "1", "1"), c("Fictifs", 
"Fictifs", "Fictifs", "Hospitalisé", "Hospitalisé", "Hospitalisé"
), c(NA, "Chir Vis", "Chir Vis", NA, "Pneumo", "Pneumo"), c(NA, 
"CHIRURGIE GENERALE ET VISCERALE", "CHIRURGIE GENERALE ET VISCERALE", 
NA, "PNEUMOLOGIE", "PNEUMOLOGIE"), c(NA, NA, "AGUI01", NA, NA, 
"CHEH00"), c("", "", "ELIZABETH", "", "", "JACQUES"
), c("0", "0", "0", "10058", "2", "2"), c("0", "0", "0", "8272", 
"0", "0"), c("0", "0", "0", "7866", "0", "0"), c("0", "0", "0", 
"-406", "0", "0"), c("0", "0", "0", "16706935.369999999", "733.93", 
"733.93"), c("0", "0", "0", "14774325.630000001", "0", "0"), 
c("0", "0", "0", "14948147.18", "0", "0"), c("0", "0", "0", 
"173821.55", "0", "0"), c("0", "0", "0", "3.4582126809785318", 
"1", "1"), c("0", "0", "0", "3.5219766877124816", "0", "0"
), c("0", "0", "0", "3.2538019169329071", "0", "0"), c("0", 
"0", "0", "-0.26817477077957452", "0", "0")), names = c("code_1", 
"type_de_sejour", "code_2", "specialite", "code_3", "medecin", 
"sejours_N2", "sejours_N1", "sejours_N", "ecart", "CA_N2", "CA_N1", 
"CA_N", "ecart", "DMS_hosp_N2", "DMS_hosp_N1", "DMS_hosp_N", 
NA), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: The error tells you all you need to know.  Your data frame contains two columns named `ecart`.  And one named `NA`!   `names(d) [1] "code_1"         "type_de_sejour" "code_2"         "specialite"     "code_3"         "medecin"        "sejours_N2"     "sejours_N1"     "sejours_N"      "ecart"         
[11] "CA_N2"          "CA_N1"          "CA_N"           "ecart"          "DMS_hosp_N2"    "DMS_hosp_N1"    "DMS_hosp_N"     NA`

Comment: thank you ! indeed it was my problem, but now I have a new one when i run the same line of code after renaming one of the variables ecart : "Error in initialize(...) : attempt to use zero-length variable name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `clean_names` function from `janitor` package:

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  filter(medecin != "")
```

```
  code_1 type_de_sejour code_2   specialite           code_3 medecin sejours_n2 sejours_n1 sejours_n ecart ca_n2 ca_n1 ca_n  ecart_2 dms_hosp_n2 dms_hosp_n1 dms_hosp_n na   
  <chr>  <chr>          <chr>    <chr>                <chr>  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      <chr>
1 9      Fictifs        Chir Vis CHIRURGIE GENERALE ~ AGUI01 ELIZAB~ 0          0          0         0     0     0     0     0       0           0           0          0    
2 1      Hospitalisé    Pneumo   PNEUMOLOGIE          CHEH00 JACQUES 2          0          0         0     733.~ 0     0     0       1           0           0          0
```